# How to install PostGIS shp2pgsql-gui on CentOS 6?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation, linux, gui

I am installing PostGIS 1.5.3 on a CentOS 6.2 virtual machine to get started web mapping with Geoserver.I have successfully installed PostgreSQL 9.1, PostGIS 1.5.3 and PgAdminIII on the system.  However, I am noticing that there are no PostGIS GUI's installed.

I was under the impression the PostGIS includes the Shapefile and DBF loader plugin for PgAdminIII even in Linux.  When I navigated to /usr/bin shp2pgsql was there but not shp2pgsl-gui.

Is there anyway to install the GUI for PostGIS in CentOS 6.2?  I am very new to Linux and the OSGeo Stack.  I have installed the above software using YUM and the rhel-6 PostgreSQL repository.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the exact version of your pgadmin btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 nice and simple solutions.

1. use the community version of open geo suite http://opengeo.org/
2. download the community version of open geo suite and extract the shp2pgsql guy

Although open geo have been quite generous on the code they have returned to the community they seem to have overlooked shp2pgsql-gui for some reason.

This solution also works for the mac

Comment: Thanks @Stevetech - Is the community version of OpenGeo Suite licensed for commercial use?

Comment: as far as i know the only difference is support.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the one-click installers at [EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload).

> The PostgreSQL installers include the database server, pgAdmin and
>   StackBuilder. The 8.x installers are supported on Ubuntu 6.06 and
>   above, Fedora 6 and above, openSUSE 10 and above, SLES 9 and above,
>   CentOS/RHEL 4 and above, Mac OS X 10.4 and above (Intel and PPC), and
>   Windows XP and above. The 9.x installers are supported on Ubuntu 8.04
>   and above, Fedora 10 and above, openSUSE 11 and above, SLES 11 and
>   above, CentOS/RHEL 5 and above, Mac OS X 10.5 and above (Intel 32 and
>   64 bit), and Windows XP and above.

After installing, you can then use the StackBuilder to add PostGIS. It should include the shp2pgsql-gui with pgadmin3.

---

Alternate answer:

pkgs.org lists shp2pgsql-gui as part of the **[postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/epel-x86_64/postgis-1.5.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html)** package. You could try replacing your current PostGIS with it. Once you've removed your old PostGIS, you can install the new one by following these steps:

1. Download the latest epel-release rpm from

   ```
   http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/6/x86_64/
   ```
2. Install epel-release rpm:

   ```
    # rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm
   ```
3. Install postgis rpm package:

   ```
    # yum install postgis
   ```

After installation, check to see if shp2pgsql-gui exists. If yes,  add the following to your pgadmin3's **plugins.ini** file under **/usr/share/pgadmin3/**:

```
;
; pgShapeLoader (Linux):
;
Title=PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader
Command=$$PGBINDIR/shp2pgsql-gui -U $$USERNAME -d $$DATABASE -p $$PORT -h $$HOSTNAME
Description=Open a PostGIS ESRI Shapefile or Plain dbf loader console to the current database.
KeyFile=$$PGBINDIR/shp2pgsql-gui
Platform=unix
ServerType=postgresql
Database=Yes
SetPassword=No
```

Comment: I have already installed PostgreSQL and PostGIS from a different repository.  Is it possible to install only the gui feature from the EPEL repository?

Comment: shp2pgsql-gui should be part of the postgis package. What we're trying to figure out now is how to enable it. Could you run find and check if shp2pqsql-gui exists already?

Comment: I did the find and it does not exist.  shp2pgsql does exist, but not shp2pgsql-gui.  I used the repoistory located here: http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php and it was named: CentOS 6 - x86_64 and I installed postgresql91-server, postgresql91-devel, postgresql91-libs

Comment: What was your the full package name of your old PostGIS install btw? Didn't realize you were using the 64-bit versions of CentOS. Edited my answer to reflect that. Hope it works this time.

Comment: As far as I know, shp2pgsql-gui is just part of the PostGIS package . I don't think you can install it by itself. You can download and extract it from a version that has it as SteveTech suggested.